# Running Node as Cron task

Tags: node.js, bash, cron

I have a simple question. I try to run a Node JS program on a Cron task via a bash script.

So, on crontab -e, I made a task @reboot that execute boot.sh :

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@reboot bash /home/pi/boot.sh
```

And my bash script :

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
cd /home/pi/Sites/node-raspberry-pi/
/usr/bin/git pull
node /home/pi/Sites/node-raspberry-pi/index.js 3000 # where 3000 is the argument of my program
exit 0
```

When I do `bash /home/pi/boot.sh`, it works as supposed.

What do I miss ?

*Note : both `crontab -e` and `bash /home/pi/boot.sh` are exectued as `pi` user.*

Comment: Use the full path to the node binary. You're also not using `bash` in the cron script but `sh`. Chances are that won't make any difference here but it's something to be aware of

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might be that your `node` cannot be found when `cron` is running; because `cron` has a limited search path. Try prefixing it with wherever you have `node` installed, so e.g., instead of

```
node /home/pi/Sites/node-raspberry-pi/index.js 3000
```

you would get

```
/usr/local/bin/node /home/pi/Sites/node-raspberry-pi/index.js 3000
```

You can also extend the searchpath for `cron`, see `man 5 crontab`. Hope this helps..